# Serenity framework didn`t work with Firefox 45.01

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity framework version 1.0.47. After update Firefox to 45 version, I can`t run UI tests in Firefox browser. Tests open browser, but didn`t navigate to application URL.

How this issue can be solved ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you past your error log ?

Comment: I am also facing similar issues , I am trying to run the serenity demo app https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-demos/tree/master/serenity-journey-demo , the tests run fine on chrome but when i run the same tests against `firefox` i see the following error 
```net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException
Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

net.serenitybdd.demos.todos.features.stepdefinitions.RecordTodoStepDefinitions.i_need_to_add_a_new_task(RecordTodoStepDefinitions.java :17)```